# Generating a text file with looped values

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

So I have a rather complex issue, at least for me, that i'm trying to reconcile in python. I've written out the problem on paper and pen, but am having trouble getting started.

Essentially, I'm attempting to make 280 text files automatically in python, that are similar, with 3 parameters varied. Only 2 of the 3 parameters change at a time, at most.

So the three parameters I have are i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] , j = [1.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.075, 0.05, and 0.025], and k = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 82.5]. The potential output looks something very similar to this:

title
File Name
geometry 1
(the value of i) 1 1.0
info (the value of j)
direction (the value of k)
another string here
another string here

So the way the problem iterates is that i will be at 1 with j going to 1.0, and then k will go through its set of 0 to 82.5. Once that happens, i will be at 1 still, with j going to 0.5, and k running all the way though its values again. Now each iterative change gets saved as its own text file.

The first text file would then be i=1, j=1.0, k=0.0. The second text file would be then i=1, j=1.0, k=15.0. And it steps down the line. I was thinking of doing a triple nested for loop, but then i'm not too sure how to set that up effectively, and then save after each iteration, while keeping the stuff not in parentheses above constant.

Any insight would be very helpful. I'm new to this still, but wound my way up into a problem like this. Go figure right?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what i understood, the below code will help you create files for each combination of i, j, k

```
i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
j = [1.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.075, 0.05, 0.025]
k = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 82.5]

file_path = '\dir\folder\'
file_header = "Field1 Field2 Field3"

for i_val in i:
    for j_val in j:
        for k_val in k:
            file_content = ' '.join([str(x) for x in [i_val, j_val, k_val]])
            with open(file_path + 'geometry' + str(i_val) + '.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(file_header)
                file.write(file_content)
```

Instead of using for loops, you can also make your code more pythonic by using `itertools.product` function which gives you the needed combinations of the list in one go.

*code update after comment from SO:*

```
from itertools import product

i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
j = [1.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.075, 0.05, 0.025]
k = [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 82.5]

file_path = '\dir\folder\'
file_header = "Field1 Field2 Field3\n"

content = list(product(*[i, j, k]))

for file_count, val in enumerate(content):
    print(val) #  for your reference
    file_content = ' '.join([str(x) for x in val])
    #print(file_content)
    with open(file_path + "geometry" + str(file_count+1) + ".txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(file_header)
        file.write(file_content)
```

This will now produce files in the mentioned path with name **geometry#** where # is file count

With your input lists, this will produce 392 files in total...I hope this is what you expected...

Comment: It has a few errors overall in it, but it definetly gave me some ideas to pursue! It doesn't create a new file for each change, and the naming convention is a bit off, but thank you!!

Comment: oops, I didn't know that, there were lot of indentation error as I had answered from mobile. I just got time to check to the output and have now updated the code. Hope this now works as you expected...